# is there any conflict in ModelAttribute

Tags: java, spring-mvc

```java
@ModelAttribute
public void addAttributes(Model model) {
    System.out.println("Méthode addAttributes appelée");
    model.addAttribute("Person", new Person(test,test,123));
}
```

If two client Login in same time may conflict happen or no?

Comment: what's your point? conflict between what? where?

Comment: There should be no conflict based on this, each query is carried by a uniquely associated thread with its own data model.

Comment: @alainlompo can you explain me when to use modelattribute because i can store data in session